# UseEffect not rerendring page once products loaded in redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I am working on e-commerce project (MERN).So i got Molla e-commerce React template for better UX/UI.

In my root function am getting all products and store them using redux like this :

```
const updateStore = () => {
    store.dispatch( getAllProducts() );
}
```

Everything was working fine until i found out that if i try to access product page for the first time (with empty localstorage as in incognito mode) i get nothing and the product object was undefined , if i refresh the page then it works fine.

The problem is when i try to access the products page with empty redux store , it doesn't wait or rerender when the data are stored.
I tryed to use `useEffect()` to wait for product change to rerender but it's not working .
This is my product page code :

```
function SingleProduct( props ) {

    let productLink= props.match.params.link;

    const {product} = props;

    const [productLoaded,setProductLoaded] = useState(false);

    useEffect( () => {
        if(productLoaded){
            productGallery();

            document.querySelector( '.skel-pro-single' ).classList.remove( 'loaded' );
    
            let imgLoad = imagesLoaded( ".product-main-image", { background: true } );
    
            imgLoad.on( 'done', function ( instance, image ) {
                document.querySelector( '.skel-pro-single' ).classList.add( 'loaded' );
            } );
        }
    }, [ productLink ] )

    useEffect(()=>{    
        if(product){
            setProductLoaded(true);
        }
    },[product])



    return (
        productLoaded ? 
        <>
            <Helmet>
                <title></title>
            </Helmet>

            <h1 className="d-none"></h1>
            <div className="main">
            

                <div className="page-content">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="product-details-top skeleton-body">
                            <div className="row skel-pro-single">
                                <div className="col-md-6">
                                    <div className="skel-product-gallery">
                                    </div>

                                     <MediaOne link={ productLink } />
                                </div>

                                <div className="col-md-6">
                                    <div className="entry-summary row">
                                        <div className="col-md-12">
                                            <div className="entry-summary1"></div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="col-md-12">
                                            <div className="entry-summary2"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                      <ProductDetailOne link={ productLink } /> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                         <DescOne link={ productLink } />

                        <h2 className="title text-center mb-4">You May Also Like</h2>

                        <RelatedProducts />
                    </div>
                </div>

                 <StickyBar link={ productLink } />

                <QuickView />
            </div>
        </>
        :
        <></>
    )
}

function mapStateToProps( state, props ) {
    return {
        product: state.data.products.filter( product => product.link == props.link )[ 0 ]
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SingleProduct);
```

I tried to wait for product change using the useEffect and productLoaded state since it's undefined on first page render but it still showing undefined.

Answer (score 0):

'product' variable, I think, is an object, be aware about what could happen if you use useEffect with that.

```
const a = {a:123}; 
const b = {a:123};
(a === b) === false
```

if it is possible see if the id or a string/number changes

The first useEffect will run before the second one so when this will run it will have productLoaded on false.

Try to gain productLoaded from props (you will not have to manage the asyncronicity of useEffect).

assuming that product is undefined before loading

```
const productLoaded = !!product;

useEffect( () => {
    if(productLoaded){
        ..."do here what you need"
    }
}, [ productLink, productLoaded ] )
```

maybe you can achieve a change in the css classes

```
<div className={`row skel-pro-single ${productLoaded?"loaded":""}`}>
```

as a suggestion try to use react as a templating with variables in the returning jsx, please don't mix js dom interaction and react interactions, they could disturb each other (react will try to report the part of the dom that he manages to the state he calculated, so could overwrite your changes made by

```
document.querySelector( '.skel-pro-single' ).classList.remove
```